# How can I add comments to a page?

Tags: comments

How can I allow people to post comments on a page?

I've put this into my page template: `<?php comments_template(); ?>` but it just says at the bottom of my page "Comments closed".

UPDATE:
If I can allow comments for one specific template for a page that would be great.

Comment: have you checked 'settings' 'discussion', and for individual pages, under 'pages' and 'quick-edit', or the 'discussion' area in 'edit page' below the page editor? when the last one does not show, click 'screen options' near the top right, and tick 'discussion' there, then scroll back down...

Comment: @Michael Ahhhhhh, the screen options solved it, thanks!!

Comment: Michael you should add that comment as an answer.. ;)

Comment: consider it done ;-)

Comment: **RE:** Allow comments for one specific template - *Comments can be enabled selectively for pages already, that's what the discussion metabox is for, check (or not) as necessary when creating/editting the page. Is the current functionality not sufficient for your needs?*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you checked under ***Admin -> Settings -> Discussion*** and for individual pages, under **pages** and **quick-edit** or the **discussion** area in **edit page** below the page editor?

When the last one does not show, click **screen options** near the top right, and tick **discussion** there, then scroll back down.

Comment: Made some minor tweaks to make the answer a little easier to follow, only minor but makes all the difference for readability.